# How to find out the closed form of a function from its parametric form?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization

In general suppose that we have a parametric curve given by:
$$
x = \phi(t) \\
y = \psi(t)
$$
Then if $\phi^{-1}$ exists it is easy to get $y$ as a function of $x$ in closed form:
$$
y = \psi(\phi^{-1}(x))
$$

But what techniques are there when $\phi^{-1}$ is not easy to compute?

---

Specifically I am dealing with the following problem:

Let us have two quadratic functions:
$$
f_A(x) = (x - \alpha)A(x - \alpha)^T \\
f_B(x) = (x - \beta)B(x - \beta)^T
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are **diagonal**, positive, full rank matrices. Let us suppose that we are trying to **minimize** both functions simultaneously. That is we are trying to find the **Pareto optimal set (POS)** (set of $x$ for which there is no other $\hat{x}$ such that $f_A(\hat{x}) <= f_A(x) \wedge  f_B(\hat{x}) <= f_B(x) $) and the **Pareto front (PF)** (image of the POS under $f_A, f_B$).

Geometrically it is clear that the necessary condition for POS is that the contours of $f_A, f_B$ must touch. That is the gradients are linearly dependent:

$$
\triangledown f_A(x) = -c \triangledown f_B(x) \\
(x - \alpha)A = -c(x - \beta)B \\
\dots \\
x= (c\beta BA^{-1}+\alpha)(I+cBA^{-1})^{-1}
$$

Thus we have a parametrization of the POS using $c\in [0; \infty)$.

[image]

Now I would like to get the **Pareto front**. When I try to plug this parametrization into $f_A, f_B$ I get a parametric description of PF. I would like to get a **closed form** description.

But I failed to construct the inverse function as mentioned at the beginning. Therefore I am looking for alternative techniques.

[image]

I think the resulting curve is a **parabola** since for some special cases I tried I got a parabola.

I would very much welcome, but do not expect, anyone to take a knack on my specific problem. I just want some hints or suggestions. If however someone would, I can edit my question to provide additional details on the things I tried.

Comment: $x= (c\beta BA^{-1}+\alpha)(I+cBA^{-1})^{-1}$. exponent ${-1}$ is missing in your solution. please double check.

Comment: basically you want to get rid of $c$ in the expression that involves $f_A$ and $f_B$. right?

Comment: @mike In a sense, yes. But I will edit my question to be more precise. Thank you for the correction!

Comment: @mike Correction: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Could you first write the closed form of the curve (POS) in the x-plane? From the condition that the two gradients are collinear, and their wedge or cross-product is 0, you'll get a quadratic equation in the x coordinates.